# SharePoint 2010 Infopath Form Problem using SOAP service

Tags: infopath, central-administration, forms-services

I have a form built for a SharePoint list which when run from InfoPath's preview mode, works fine.  It makes a call to a data connection (which has been converted to a connection file and stored in a data connection library in my SharePoint site.

I can see that it talks to the service server (I see the request successfully authenticate in the IIS logs, and I see the service log report that it did what it was supposed to).

When I run the form from the SharePoint site, though, the form will fail.
I'll get a correlation id error that basically says the external server refused the connect due to authentication. The service server's IIS logs show that it blocked access to the service... and the service log shows nothing since the request didn't make it that far.

Googling, I found a page that mentions that when doing what I'm doing, the problem [might be a double- or multi-hop authentication problem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms771995(v=office.14).aspx).
Reading that, it discusses how to set in your SharePoint Central Admin, you need to mess with the InfoPath Form Services settings "Configure InfoPath Forms Services Web Service Proxy" and turn on features. "Enable InfoPath Forms Services Web service proxy" and "Enable InfoPath Forms Services Web service proxy for user forms"
You then are supposed to edit your udcx file to set the allow proxy settings to true.

I'm missing something from this article... I'm not doing something right and I'm looking for others who've successfully set this up and might know if there's a trick or a step i'm missing.

I think I'm trying to make things work like "Multi-tier Web service Authentication using the Proxy: " part of the article mentions... but something just isn't working for me.

Comment: What is your form security set to? See if it is "Domain"

Comment: When i look at the form in IP designer, in Form Options, i don't see a "Security and Trust" entry.

Comment: only time i get that option is if i start from scratch and create a form for a form library... not start with a a SP list and design form from there

Comment: when i do create a new form for a form library utilizing the same data connection file, and have set security and trust to "domain" i still have the same problem.   Authentication isn't making it to the service server

Comment: It sounds odd that Preview/Filler is working but browser is not. is the form set up to be browser enabled?

Comment: while i'm digging... is there a way to confirm proper operation of the "Enable InfoPath Forms Services Web service proxy" web proxy?  like some way to see if traffic is traversing it?

Comment: Adding to this... in looking at all the logs and running various tests, I've found that when I use the InfoPath preview function to hit the external web service, the web service IIS shows me the request came from the local machine the preview is running on. When I run the form from the SP list, the web service IIS tells me the request from an IP that is mapped to another web application on the same SharePoint server where my web application is housed.    ON a second (production) farm, the IP returned is for the actual machine the web app is housed on... not the web app's IP

Comment: I've stopped looking into this for the moment... In digging, I've found a parallel problem where I get similar errors trying to do UserProfile Service lookups within the same https sharepoint site or site collection.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm sorry that I couldn't be of more help. If you create a completely new form, do you see the Security/Trust settings?

Comment: you only see those settings when working with form/form libraries... not when you attempt to work on a form either starting from a sharepoint list, or attaching to a sharepoint list